# Placeholder property of HTML not working properly in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, placeholder

Please consider the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But in IE 10, the placeholder text appears in italics. I want the placeholder text in IE10 in normal font style.

Answer (score 0):

In IE you can style placeholder as follow:

```
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-style:normal
}
```